# Web Service + Soap + Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap

I'm developing a WS using KSOAP, I tested it using **SoapUI** and it worked well.
When I try to use it on my android code I get the exception below.

I have checked all my code but still can't find the error

When I try  to debbug I get the exception on this line:

```
SoapPrimitive resposta = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

on the UserDao class

```
public class UserDAO {

private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.12:5037/EngeplayWebService/services/UsuarioDAO?wsdl";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://engecard.engeplay.card.com/";

private static final String INSERIR = "InserirUsuario";
private static final String BUSCARTODOS= "buscarTodosUsuarios";
private static final String EXCLUIR= "ExcluirUsuario";
private static final String BUSCARUSUARIO= "buscarUsuarioPorId";
private static final String ATUALIZAR = "atualizarUsuario";



public boolean InserirUsuario(User usuario){
    SoapObject inserirUsuario = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, INSERIR);
    SoapObject usr = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "User");

    usr.addProperty("id", usuario.getId());
    usr.addProperty("nome", usuario.getNome());
    usr.addProperty("numeroCartao", usuario.getNumeroCartao());

    inserirUsuario.addSoapObject(usr);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(inserirUsuario);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("urn:" + INSERIR, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive resposta = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        return Boolean.parseBoolean(resposta.toString());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnEfetuarLogin;
EditText edtTxtUsuario;
EditText edtTxtSenha;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    UserDAO dao = new UserDAO();
    User usr = new User(2,"TesteNovo","323223323244");
    boolean resultado = dao.InserirUsuario(usr);
    Log.d("Exemplo: ", resultado + "");


    }
    }
```

The exception:

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: '1' faultactor: 'null'         detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41d12308
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:147)
 at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
 at com.card.engeplay.engecardsystem.UserDAO.InserirUsuario(UserDAO.java:43)
 at com.card.engeplay.engecardsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
```

WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ax21="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com/xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com">
<wsdl:documentation>
    Please Type your service description here
</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com/xsd">
        <xs:complexType name="Usuario">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nome" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numeroCartao" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema xmlns:ax22="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com">
        <xs:import namespace="http://engecard.engeplay.card.com/xsd"/>
        <xs:element name="buscarTodosUsuarios">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="buscarTodosUsuariosResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="ax22:Usuario"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="buscarUsuarioPorId">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="buscarUsuarioPorIdResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="ax22:Usuario"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="atualizarUsuario">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax22:Usuario"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="atualizarUsuarioResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="InserirUsuario">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax22:Usuario"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="InserirUsuarioResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ExcluirUsuario">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax22:Usuario"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ExcluirUsuarioResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="buscarTodosUsuariosRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:buscarTodosUsuarios"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="buscarTodosUsuariosResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:buscarTodosUsuariosResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="InserirUsuarioRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:InserirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="InserirUsuarioResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:InserirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="buscarUsuarioPorIdRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:buscarUsuarioPorId"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="buscarUsuarioPorIdResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:buscarUsuarioPorIdResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ExcluirUsuarioRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:ExcluirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ExcluirUsuarioResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:ExcluirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="atualizarUsuarioRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:atualizarUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="atualizarUsuarioResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:atualizarUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="UsuarioDAOPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarTodosUsuarios">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:buscarTodosUsuariosRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:buscarTodosUsuarios"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:buscarTodosUsuariosResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:buscarTodosUsuariosResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="InserirUsuario">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:InserirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:InserirUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:InserirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:InserirUsuarioResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarUsuarioPorId">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:buscarUsuarioPorIdRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:buscarUsuarioPorId"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:buscarUsuarioPorIdResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:buscarUsuarioPorIdResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ExcluirUsuario">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:ExcluirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:ExcluirUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:ExcluirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:ExcluirUsuarioResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:atualizarUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:atualizarUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:atualizarUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:atualizarUsuarioResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOSoap11Binding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarTodosUsuarios">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:buscarTodosUsuarios" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="InserirUsuario">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:InserirUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarUsuarioPorId">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:buscarUsuarioPorId" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ExcluirUsuario">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ExcluirUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:atualizarUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOSoap12Binding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarTodosUsuarios">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:buscarTodosUsuarios" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="InserirUsuario">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:InserirUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarUsuarioPorId">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:buscarUsuarioPorId" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ExcluirUsuario">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:ExcluirUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:atualizarUsuario" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOHttpBinding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
    <http:binding verb="POST"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarTodosUsuarios">
        <http:operation location="buscarTodosUsuarios"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="InserirUsuario">
        <http:operation location="InserirUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="buscarUsuarioPorId">
        <http:operation location="buscarUsuarioPorId"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="ExcluirUsuario">
        <http:operation location="ExcluirUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="atualizarUsuario">
        <http:operation location="atualizarUsuario"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="UsuarioDAO">
    <wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOSoap11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://192.168.0.121:8080/EngeplayWebService/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOSoap12Binding">
        <soap12:address location="http://192.168.0.121:8080/EngeplayWebService/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://192.168.0.121:8080/EngeplayWebService/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpEndpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

WSDL LOG

```
[ERROR] 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java:630)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:153)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:206)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
public class UserDAO {
public boolean InserirUsuario(User usuario){

    try {
        Connection conn = ConectarMysql.Conecta();

        String queryInserir = "INSERT INTO Usuarios VALUES (null, ?, ?)"; //campo null pq o campo id da tabela é auto increment

        PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);
        ppStm.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        ppStm.setString(2, usuario.getNumeroCartao());

        ppStm.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String nome;
private String numeroCartao;


public User(){

}

public User(int id, String nome, String numeroCartao) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.numeroCartao = numeroCartao;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getNumeroCartao() {
    return numeroCartao;
}
public void setNumeroCartao(String numeroCartao) {
    this.numeroCartao = numeroCartao;
}



}
```

Class User from android project

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String nome;
private String numeroCartao;


public User(){

}

public User(int id, String nome, String numeroCartao) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.numeroCartao = numeroCartao;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getNumeroCartao() {
    return numeroCartao;
}
public void setNumeroCartao(String numeroCartao) {
    this.numeroCartao = numeroCartao;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by replacingthe line

SoapObject usr = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Usuario");

for 
SoapObject usr = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "User");

as it was on my WS XML